# Get IIS version or other IIS Server variables in Asp.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

In Asp.Net Core 2.x I could obtain IIS information via Server Vars like so:

```
  IServerVariablesFeature serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
  string iis_version = serverVars["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
  string app_pool_id = serverVars["APP_POOL_ID"];
```

This approach worked even when using Kestrel as a reverse proxy.
However, accessing IIS server variables this ways appears to have stopped working in Asp.Net Core 3.x.  Starting at that time and now also in Asp.Net 5.0 the `IServerVariablesFeature` no longer exists and when requesting it null is returned.

How can I get access to the IIS server variables (ie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in Asp.Net 5.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, My test shows that this code can still work in Asp.net 5, and IIS variables can be obtained.
[image]
Here is the code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;

 IServerVariablesFeature serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
  string iis_version = serverVars["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
  string app_pool_id = serverVars["APP_POOL_ID"];
  string runtime = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
```

The Asp.net core version information for IServerVariablesFeature is also mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.iservervariablesfeature?view=aspnetcore-5.0#moniker-applies-to).

> Applies to
> ASP.NET Core
> 5.0 3.1 3.0 2.2

So I think you should carefully check the other code in the application, whether it may be a misspelling when referencing variables, or a problem with the installation of [Asp.net Core 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0).

Comment: That's insightful and will help with my debugging.  I have verified that you are correct by checking it with a new basic web app.  My large web app that is exhibiting the odd behavior has been upgraded many times and was started in .Net core RC2 prior to the 1.0 release and upgraded all along the way.  I must not have upgraded something right when going to 3.1 so I'm off to hunt for that.

Comment: It's important to note that this feature is only available in Asp.Net 5 when running in the IIS process. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a more research it turns out the reason I do not have access to the `IServerVariablesFeature` feature is because I run my web application OutOfProcess.

Starting in .NetCore 3.0 the IServerVariablesFeature feature is only available when running in process in IIS. Otherwise it returns null. This seems like a feature regression given that the feature worked even when running out of process in Asp.Net Core 2.2.